# Set Row Source property to SQL statement in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

I tried to set the following SQL statement into Row Source property in Access but the statement did not seem to be executed:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ProjectName FROM tblProjects ORDER BY ProjectName.
```

Does it mean that I got the syntax wrong?

Comment: Did you cut and paste this into SQL view in the query design window to check what is returned?

Comment: Terminating a SQL statement with a period rather than a semicolon would be a syntax error but perhaps just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SQL was wrong, you would get an error when opening the ComboBox.
Are there projects with a non-empty ProjectName in the table?
Also check the ComboBox properties `ColumnCount`, `ColumnWith`, `ListRows`. The `RowSourceType` must be set to `Table/Query`!

Comment: Thanks for your reply Olivier. In fact, the sql statement was injected as an item into the list.

Comment: OK, you solved the problem. I have some other thoughts that may help others with the same problem: Make sure the TextColor of the ComboBox is not white! It is a good idea to store the SQL as a query. It allows you to test it separately from the ComboBox. I usually use a "qcbo" prefix for such queries (qcboProject). It is also easier to find your queries in a large application. Imagine searching through the properties of all the forms, reports and controls of your application, if there is a major change in the DB.